# transform bound for google map

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

i have wms layer with coming geoserver and it's bounds is

```
 bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(417138.6205791628, 4243634.852681775, 486211.1950145211, 4331542.555877601).transform(WGS84, WGS84_google_mercator);
```

but when i use google baselayer, in the opening map it shows me full extends how can i transform my bound with harmonic google. ?

Answer (score 2):

Your transform goes from WGS84 to mercator. However, the coordinates of your bounds are not in WGS84 (a geographic coordinate system , with lat/long in degrees). Maybe your coordinates are already in mercator, or you should try to identify the correct coordinate system of your source before projecting the data.

Answer (score 0):

i add projection: WGS84_google_mercator on map it s works also

```
var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(3947950.0553875, 4679507.9024374);

map.setCenter(position, 10);
```

i used for bounds